# Type Hierarchy in Agda

Tags: types, hierarchy, agda

I am trying to figure out how type hierarchies work in Agda.

Assuming I define a set type X:

```
X : Set
```

and then proceed to constructing an inductive type

```
data Y : X -> Set where
```

What is the type of `X -> Set`? Is it Set or Type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, why not ask Agda itself? I'm going to use excellent Agda mode for Emacs. We start with:

```
module Hierarchy where

postulate
  X : Set

data Y : X → Set where
  -- empty
```

We have to load the file using `C-c C-l`; this typechecks the file, turns `?`s into holes, does syntax highlighting and so on.

Now, there is a command "Infer (deduce) type" available via `C-c C-d`, so let's use that:

```
> C-c C-d
Expression:
> Y
X → Set
```

Right, that makes sense. We defined `Y : X → Set`, so it should come as no surprise. Let's ask again:

```
> C-c C-d
Expression:
> X → Set
Set₁
```

So, there you have it: `Y : X → Set : Set₁`.

---

While the first part answers the question and shows you how to check this stuff yourself, doing that everytime would be dull, at least. Here's how it works:

To avoid paradoxes, we require

```
Set i : Set (i + 1)
```

which gives you the (infinite) hierarchy of `Set`s. If you had `Set : Set` (which Agda allows via the `--type-in-type` flag), you could derive contradiction such as [this one](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g53cfr/l20.html/l20.html).

This also gives us a simple rule for functions:

```
A : Set i
B : A → Set j

(a : A) → B a : Set (max i j)
```

Applying this to your example:

```
X   : Set
Set : Set₁

X → Set : Set (max 0 1)
X → Set : Set₁
```