# Appropriate use of universe polymorphism

Tags: set, hierarchy, agda, parametric-polymorphism

I've been working for a couple of weeks on an Agda project, glibly ignoring level polymorphism as much as I can. Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately) I seem to have reached the point where I need to start understanding it.

Until now I've been using level variables only when they are needed as a second argument to `Rel` (or third argument to `REL`). Otherwise I have omitted them, just using `Set` directly. Now I have some client code that explicitly quantifies over levels `a` and tries to pass some types of the form `Set a` to my existing code, which is now insufficiently polymorphic. In the example below, `quibble` represents the client code, and `_[_]×[_]_` and `≈-List` are typical of my existing code which just uses `Set`.

```
module Temp where

open import Data.List
open import Data.Product
open import Level
open import Relation.Binary

-- Direct product of binary relations.
_[_]×[_]_ : {ℓ₁ ℓ₂ : Level} {A B C D : Set} → A × B → REL A C ℓ₁ → REL B D ℓ₂ → C × D → Set (ℓ₁ ⊔ ℓ₂)
(a , b) [ _R_ ]×[ _S_ ] (c , d) = a R c × b S d

-- Extend a setoid (A, ≈) to List A.
data ≈-List {ℓ : Level} {A : Set} (_≈_ : Rel A ℓ) : Rel (List A) ℓ where
   [] : ≈-List _≈_ [] []
   _∷_ : {x y : A} {xs ys : List A} → (x≈y : x ≈ y) → (xs≈ys : ≈-List _≈_ xs ys) → ≈-List _≈_ (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys)

quibble : {a ℓ : Level} {A : Set a} → Rel A ℓ → Rel (List (A × A)) ℓ
quibble _≈_ = ≈-List (λ x y → x [ _≈_ ]×[ _≈_ ] y)
```

Here, I can extend the inductive definition of `≈-List` with an extra level parameter `a` so that it can take a type argument of type `Set a`, but then I'm unclear as to how the universes of the input and output relations should change. And then problem spills out to more complex definitions such as `_[_]×[_]_` where I'm even less sure how to proceed.

How should I generalise the signatures in the example given, so that `quibble` compiles? Are there general rules I can follow? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924509/type-hierarchy-in-agda?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can generalize it to arbitrary universe levels and still have `quibble` compile. The product of binary relations can be generalized quite easily: you just have to decorate `Set`s with one letter for each type `A` through `D`:

```
_[_]×[_]_ : ∀ {a b c d ℓ₁ ℓ₂}
  {A : Set a} {B : Set b} {C : Set c} {D : Set d} →
  A × B → REL A C ℓ₁ → REL B D ℓ₂ → C × D → Set (ℓ₁ ⊔ ℓ₂)
(a , b) [ _R_ ]×[ _S_ ] (c , d) = a R c × b S d
```

Yes, sadly universe polymorphism usually requires fair amount of boilerplate code. Anyways, the only way to generalize `≈-List` is to allow `Set a` for `A`. So, you start with:

```
data ≈-List {a ℓ} {A : Set a} (_≈_ : Rel A ℓ) : Rel (List A) a where
```

But here's the problem: what's the type of the `_∷_` constructor? The type of `x` (and `y`, `xs`, `ys`) is `A : Set a`, type of `x≈y` is `x ≈ y : Rel A ℓ = A → A → Set ℓ`. This implies that type of the constructor should be `Set (max a ℓ)`, or in standard library notation `Set (a ⊔ ℓ)`.

So yes, if we generalize `≈-List` to work with `A : Set a`, we have to declare its type as `Rel (List A) (a ⊔ ℓ)`. You could make it `Rel (List A) ℓ` by not having `x`, `y`, `xs` and `ys` - but I suppose that's not an option. And that's a dead end: either use `Set`s (because `zero ⊔ ℓ = ℓ`) or change `quibble`.

---

`quibble` might not be salvagable, but let me give you one tip that's nice to know when you deal with universe polymorphism. Sometimes you have a type `A : Set a` and something that requires type `Set (a ⊔ b)`. Now, surely `a ≤ a ⊔ b`, so by going from `Set a` to `Set (a ⊔ b)` cannot cause any contradictions (in the usual `Set : Set` sense). And of course, the standard library has a tool for this. In the `Level` module, there's a data type called `Lift`, let's look at its definition:

```
record Lift {a ℓ} (A : Set a) : Set (a ⊔ ℓ) where
  constructor lift
  field lower : A
```

Notice that is has only one field of type `A` (which is in `Set a`) and `Lift A` itself has a type `Set (a ⊔ ℓ)`. So, if you have `x : A : Set a`, you can move to higher level via `lift`: `lift a : Lift A : Set (a ⊔ ℓ)` and vice versa: if you have something in `Lift A`, you can lower it back using... erm.. `lower`: `x : Lift A : Set (a ⊔ ℓ)` and `lower x : A : Set a`.

---

I did a quick search through pile of my code snippets and it came up with this example: how to implement safe `head` on `Vec`tors with just the dependent eliminator. Here's the dependent eliminator (also known as *induction principle*) for vectors:

```
Vec-ind : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a} (P : ∀ n → Vec A n → Set p)
  (∷-case : ∀ {n} x xs → P n xs → P (suc n) (x ∷ xs))
  ([]-case : P 0 []) →
  ∀ n (v : Vec A n) → P n v
Vec-ind P ∷-case []-case ._ [] = []-case
Vec-ind P ∷-case []-case ._ (x ∷ xs)
  = ∷-case x xs (Vec-ind P ∷-case []-case _ xs)
```

Since we have to deal with empty vector, we'll use type level function that returns `A` for non-empty vectors and `⊤` for empty ones:

```
Head : ∀ {a} → ℕ → Set a → Set a
Head 0       A = ⊤
Head (suc n) A = A
```

But here's the problem: we ought to return `Set a`, but `⊤ : Set`. So we `Lift` it:

```
Head 0       A = Lift ⊤
Head (suc n) A = A
```

And then we can write:

```
head : ∀ {n a} {A : Set a} → Vec A (suc n) → A
head {A = A} = Vec-ind (λ n xs → Head n A) (λ x _ _ → x) (lift tt) _
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried using `Rel (List A) (a ⊔ ℓ)` as the return type of `≈-List`, but wasn't sure then how to push through to `_[_]×[_]_` (in particular whether the level arguments of the sets A through D should be mentioned in the result type). But just adding the extra a through d parameters seems to do the trick with the code I have. (Maybe `quibble` wasn't representative after all.) Thanks for pointing out `lift` and `lower`, and for another really good answer.