# Lifting a type to higher universe

Tags: agda, dependent-type

In a formalization that I'm working on, I need to lift the Unit type, from Agda standard library, which is defined on universe `Set` to a polymorphic one like `Set a`.

How can I do that? I know that I could just define another type, like this one:

```
record Unit {l} : Set l where
   constructor unit
```

which is universe polymorphic. But, I believe that should have a more idiomatic solution to this problem. Can someone provide me a solution or if there's no way explain the reason to me?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/issues/71) discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, searching a bit the standard library, I found the tool needed in `Level` module. The solution is to use the type `Lift`:

```
record Lift {a ℓ} (A : Set a) : Set (a ⊔ ℓ) where
  constructor lift
  field lower : A
```

The unit type

```
 record ⊤ : Set where
   constructor tt
```

can be lifted to higher universe levels using `Lift ⊤`. I found the solution reading part of the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961465/appropriate-use-of-universe-polymorphism).